# How do I get the first Cell coordinates for a range for using Interop.Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am working on a small addin for excel for where I work and I need to find the starting position (x and y) for a selected cell range.

Here is some code:

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Range thisRange = thisSheet.Cells.Application.Selection.SpecialCells(
                             Excel.XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible,
                             Type.Missing);
```

where thisSheet is an `Excel.Worksheet`.

I can find the number of rows and columns using:

```
int r = thisRange.Rows.Count;
int c = thisRange.Columns.Count;
```

but I am trying to find the X and Y position of the first cell in the selected range. Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: In a normal range, to get the address of first cell (top left one) would be `Range(whatever).Cells(1,1).Address`. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by using [Range.Row](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.row?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Row) and [Range.Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.column?view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Range_Column)